# Python / Pymongo variable for collection name in db insert command

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have this small piece of code that basically takes a list and runs a loop, running search queries against twitter, for each item in the list. I want each item in the list to be a collection name but for some reason I can't figure out how to make `db<collection_name_variable>.insert(post)>` to actually work:

I get an error:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'Database' and 'str'

I know this is probably very basic but I am just learning.

```
from twython import Twython
from pymongo import *

conn = Connection('localhost')
db = conn.nosqltweets
twitter = Twython()

types = ['mongodb', 'cassandra', 'couchdb']

for nosql in types:
    search_results = twitter.searchTwitter(q=nosql, rpp="100")
    for tweet in search_results["results"]:
        from_user = tweet['from_user'].encode('utf-8')
        text = tweet['text']
        created_at = tweet['created_at']
        id_str = tweet['id_str']
        post = { 'id_str': id_str, 'from_user': from_user, 'created_at': created_at }
        insert = db + nosql + ".insert(post)"
        insert
```

Comment: You are trying to add / concatenate object of type "Database" (db) and "String" (nosql) using "+" operator.

Comment: Fenikso yep, actually as surprising as it is I did understand the problem just didn't understand how to solve it. Thanks for the comment!

Comment: @Ajj you can escape inline code by using backtick (`) no need to tweak it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Replace:

```
insert = db + nosql + ".insert(post)"
insert
```

with:

```
db[nosql].insert(post)
```

Comment: Sorry diliop that didn't work, I'd answer my own question but it won't let me here is what I did:

I used getattr(db, nosql)

collection = getattr(db, nosql)
collection.insert(post)

Comment: Unless there is something missing from your code above, this should work. db is of type `<class 'pymongo.database.Database'>` and you can use both dot notation i.e. `db.couchdb` or `dict` member accessing i.e. `db['couchdb']` to get an instance of `<class 'pymongo.collection.Collection'>` on which you call `insert()`.

Comment: diliop you are right, apparently I didn't try what you posted correctly because I tried it again this evening and it worked! Thanks!!

Comment: Got it sorry I'm new to this site!